# how to pass a variable into another class in same package

Tags: java, collections

I have one Java class in which i have a collection variable and I am doing some calculation and storing some value into that variable and in another class in same package I want to use that variable so it can print the value in that class. Here below is the collection syntax:

```
public static HashMap<String, Double> hMap3=new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

and now I am getting some value here like this in this class

```
hMap3.put(ID,z);
```

now I want to get this hMap3 value in another PDF generating class I am trying like this and it is showing an error

```
table.addCell(hMap3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not using hMap3 but hMap1.

You could add the variable as a field in your main class as:

```
public static HashMap<String,String>hMap1=new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then you should be able to fetch this in another class by using:

```
table.addCell(mainclass.hMap3);
```

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: yea sir i have tried and i am using hMap3 only so mistakenly i have print here and the way you are telling me its not printing....both class are servlet so because of that is there any problem...?

Comment: as you said i have done sir... its working half of the way i mean its not showing error for hMap3 but its showing error for method addCell...

Comment: sir i try to rectify more question properly... my task is i have to calculate salary using some value from xls and some value from database.. so i have calculated the salary now that is store in hMap3 variable now what i want i want to print this in pdf so tell me what should i follow...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the get(key) method of HashMap to get the value that is stored.

Each entry is HashMap is stored as a key/value pair using the put(key, value) method.

You need to make the Hashmap as a class level variable and generate getter method for it and then call the getter method in another class by using the object of the class in which HashMap is stored.

You can get value as

```
        String value = hMap3.get(ID);
        table.addCell(value);
```

create a class like below and add map entries to you Hashmap in from main method

```
  public class A  {
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
public void populateMap(String ID, String z) {
    map.put(ID, z);
}
public HashMap<String, String> getMap() {
    return map;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    a.populateMap("1234", "New Object Stored");
}
 }
```

Then create another class in same package like below

```
  class B {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    HashMap<String, String > map = a.getMap();
    table.add(map.get("1234"));
}
   }
```

Comment: sir please can you explain more this i am not familiar with collection methods so please can you tell me what method i have to create in that class and both class are servlet so can i call their object....?

Comment: yea sir i have checked your answer but actually its my fault i didnt ask question properly actually my task is retrieve the value and pass them into pdf cell i want to print the value in pdf cell ....i got some suggestion here that addCell(Classname.hMap3) its working but now another error is coming The method addCell(PdfPCell) in the type PdfPTable is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,Double>)" so help me in this or either i will print my whole code here...

Comment: yea sir it is some what ok but now it is looking for ID its not able to recognize it i have put like this table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(XMLParsrr.hMap3.get(ID))));

Comment: Try this if you want to add value of z that you had put in hMap3 object. -----
  table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(hMap3.get(ID).toString())));

Comment: table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(XMLParsrr.hMap3.get(ID)).toString()));--- Use the String value that you gave for ID when storing like --"234". and put toString because the value you want is a double and Paragragh class takes String as an argument

Comment: Did you find any luck with the solution?

Comment: sir i am printing the whole code in another link because your suggestions are correct but this is related to another thing..

Comment: sir here is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412874/how-to-pass-one-collection-variable-value-into-another-pdf-generating-class

Comment: you said .toString that way still it was not working the link i have sent here just have a look on that you will understand my task and give me idea what should i do..?

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare hMap3 as Static, in your MainClass

   `public static HashMap<String,String> hMap3;`
2. Create an instance in MainClass:

   `hMap1=new HashMap<String, String>();`
3. Access hMap3 in another package class, using this:

   `MainClass.hMap3` , or in your case: `table.addCell(MainClass.hMap3);`
4. Make sure addCell method isn't "non-static":

   `static public .. addCell() {}`

Comment: its working sir but my problem is now changed actually addCell method of pdf class in which i am trying to print this value but what it is saying now  this message is coming in my eclipse id "The method addCell(PdfPCell) in the type PdfPTable is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,String>)"

Comment: I guess you want to use the get(Object key) method from Class HashMap<Key,Value> :  table.addCell(MainClass.hMap3.get(yourKey));

Comment: Or, maybe you want to specify me what addCell method does exactly

Answer (score 0):

table.addCell might be throwing error because addCell might not take a HashMap object as an argument. Check What does the addCell(...) method takes as an argument and pass that.