# how to pass one collection variable value into another pdf generating class

Tags: java, servlets, collections

i Have one XML parser class in which i am reading XML class and parsing and on the basis of some value which i am getting from database and with both values i am calculating salary that i have done now i want to pass this variable into another pdf class wher i want to generate pdf for the particular ID associated person

```
public class XMLParser extends HttpServlet {
    public static HashMap<String, String> hMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static HashMap<String, String> hMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static HashMap<String, Double> hMap3 = new HashMap<String, Double>();


    public static String series1, series2, ID;
    int s1, s2;
    double s3;
    static double z;

    public void getAllUserNames(String fileName) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Document doc = db.parse(file);
                Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();
                // Print root element of the document
                System.out.println("Root element of the document: " + docEle.getNodeName());

                NodeList studentList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("emplopyee");
                // NodeList st1 = docEle.getElementsByTagName("emplopyee");

                // Print total student elements in document
                System.out.println("Total emplopyee: " + studentList.getLength());

                if (studentList != null && studentList.getLength() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.getLength(); i++) {

                        Node node = studentList.item(i);

                        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                            System.out.println("=====================");

                            Element e = (Element)node;


                            NodeList nodeList1 = e.getElementsByTagName("ID");
                            ID = nodeList1.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();


                            System.out.println("ID: " + nodeList1.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                            NodeList nodeList2 = e.getElementsByTagName("Name");
                            series1 = nodeList2.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println("Name: " + nodeList2.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                            NodeList nodeList3 = e.getElementsByTagName("Days");


                            String series2 = nodeList3.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                            s3 = Double.parseDouble(series2);
                            System.out.println(s3);
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            Connection con =
                                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", null);
                            Statement st = con.createStatement();
                            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from emp1 where eid = '" + ID + "' ");

                            while (rs.next()) {
                                int n1 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
                                String n2 = rs.getString(2);
                                int n3 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(3));
                                int n4 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(4));
                                System.out.println(n1);
                                System.out.println(n2);
                                System.out.println(n3);
                                System.out.println(n4);
                                z = s3 * n3;

                                System.out.println(z);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    hMap3.put(ID, z);
                    System.out.println(hMap3); //----> this thing i want to print in pdf
                }


                else {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                                                                                       java.io.IOException {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        parser.getAllUserNames("D:\\employee.xml");
        ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/FirstPdf");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

another pdf generating class

```
public class FirstPdf extends HttpServlet {
    private static String FILE = "c:/temp/SecondPdf.pdf";
    private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
    private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
    private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16, Font.BOLD);
    private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD);

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                                                                                       java.io.IOException {
        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
            document.open();
            addMetaData(document);
            addTitlePage(document);
            addContent(document);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
        document.addTitle("Salary PDF");
        document.addSubject("Using iText");
        document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
        document.addAuthor("Saurabh");
        document.addCreator("Saurabh Gupta");
    }

    private static void addTitlePage(Document document) throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();


        preface.add(new Paragraph("Title of the document", catFont));

        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);

        preface.add(new Paragraph("Report generated by: " + System.getProperty("user.name") + ", " + new Date(),
                                  smallBold));
        addEmptyLine(preface, 3);
        preface.add(new Paragraph("This document describes something which is very important ", smallBold));

        addEmptyLine(preface, 8);

        preface.add(new Paragraph("This document is simple demonstration of generating salry slip).", redFont));

        document.add(preface);

        document.newPage();
    }

    private static void addContent(Document document) throws DocumentException {
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor("First page", catFont);
        anchor.setName("First Page");

        Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

        Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 1", subFont);
        Section subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Here we go"));

        subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 2", subFont);
        subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 1"));
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 2"));
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 3"));


        createList(subCatPart);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        addEmptyLine(paragraph, 5);
        subCatPart.add(paragraph);


        createTable(subCatPart);

        now add;
        all;
        this;
        to the;
        document;
        document.add(catPart);


        anchor = new Anchor("Second Chapter", catFont);
        anchor.setName("Second Chapter");

        Second parameter;
        is the;
        number of;
        the chapter;
        catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

        subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory", subFont);
        subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("This is a very important message"));


        document.add(catPart);

    }

    private static void createTable(Section subCatPart) throws BadElementException {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);


        PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Employee ID"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("No of days that person came"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);


        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Salary for the month"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);


        table.setHeaderRows(1);

        table.addCell("1.1");
        table.addCell("1.2");
        table.addCell("1.3");
        table.addCell("1.4");
        table.addCell("2.1");
        table.addCell("2.2");
        table.addCell("2.3");
        table.addCell("2.4");
        subCatPart.add(table);
    }

    private static void createList(Section subCatPart) {
        List list = new List(true, false, 10);
        list.add(new ListItem("First point"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Second point"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Third point"));
        subCatPart.add(list);
    }

    private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(""));
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ServletRequest#setAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) and set data in request as attribute

use [ServletRequest#getAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) to get data back from request.

---

sample code:

```
public class XMLParser extends HttpServlet {
   ...

    ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/FirstPdf");

    request.setAttribute(key,value);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}


public class FirstPdf extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,java.io.IOException {
        Object value = request.getAttribute(key);
        ...
    }  
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, i have set like this request.setAttribute(ID,z); in XMLParser Servlet and now how to print this value in FirstPdf Servlet what i have to use

Comment: use `request.getAttribute(ID)`

Comment: sir i can print the ID like this   request.setAttribute(ID,total2); total2 is a variable which is holding z value ,z is double so i have converted into string but same way i am trying to print total2 its coming blank in pdf but ID is printing

Comment: Sure your have tried `setAttribute()` to set the value in first servlet and `getAttribute()` to get the value in second servlet?

Comment: If its not working then use session attribute that is `HttpSession#getAttribute()` and `HttpSession#setAttribute()`. one level upper than servlet request. you can get http session from servlet request

Comment: and sir when i am usingrequest.getAttribute(XMLParser.ID,XMLParser.total2) so it is showing error so i have changed like this  request.setAttribute(XMLParser.ID,XMLParser.total2); its working but total2 is empty when i am printing it in     table.addCell(XMLParser.total2);

Comment: oh no why don't you click on the link that I have shared for `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()`? Look at the arguments. read more about it.

Comment: ok i understand setAttribute concept still i am not getting how to print that total2 value there..

Comment: `setAttribute(key,value)` set a value as attribute against key and in another servlet get it using `value = getAttribut(key)` where key is same in both the servlet.

Comment: sir my task is very big ...u read my salary calculation part properly..i will have xml file in that n number of person wid there details and i have to calculate the salary and this salary i have to add wid their ids and this id and salary has to pass in pdf and this pdf has to save again with id and send on mails...like that plz guide me...

Comment: you can pass a `Map<String,Double>` as value that contains all information. `setAttribute()` accepts `Object`

Comment: according to your suggestion i have tried i am getting lke this key is ID and values is total2 in my case so i am doing like this request.setAttribute(ID,total2) here it is not showing any error and now in another servlet XMLParser.total2= (String) request.getAttribute(XMLParser.ID); i am doing like this and printing in addCell(XMLParser.total2) its not coming again... same result

Comment: `ID` and `z` are static in `XMLParser` class then why don't you use `XMLParser.z` directly? Not a good way but you can try.

Comment: sir its coming i have just changed the placed of ID and total2 i mean  request.setAttribute(total2,ID); like this and in another servlet like this  XMLParser.ID= (String) request.getAttribute(XMLParser.total2); its printing i am surprised sir i have reach half the way of my task i need your guidance

Comment: i have to generate n number of employees pdf same time and particular id should hold that salary and associated with pdf so just tell me how to generate n number of pdf according to employees and just u can have look on my first servlet and i will get back you by tomorrow morning please sir.. and if it ispossible then give me your mail id or anythng so i can check it.

Comment: sir i need your help are you there..?

Answer (score 0):

Why does  FirstPdf extends from HttpServlet ? I would not put any domain logic inside a servlet. The servlet should just be a client for the services other classes provide. Extract the XML stuff into a class and the PDF stuff into a class. Than let the servlet use this classes.

Comment: sir i will do later those things because i wanted to execute these things first with normal flow because task is big i have to create salary generator...so i am just moving with first easy steps later i will convert it completely with struts and hibernate first i want to go with simple ways